# TCP IP Packets in 5G

Tags: ip

How TCP/IP packets behave in 5G communication with shorter time slots duration. Does shorter slot duration improve the TCP/IP packet level latency.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question does not keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes shorter slot times and higher RF bandwidth is the main factors for lower latency.